# jssor wrong arrow arrange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jssor

I have a page car.asp with jssor slider which is included from index.asp

So when I load directly page car.asp I got arrows in right position

[image]

But when I load this page car.asp into index.asp another div I got arrows in wrong position

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Maybe it happens because `jssor.slider.js` on line 3337 have a syntax error `self.$Relocate = function (conainerWidth, containerHeight) {` `conainerWidth` instead `containerWidth`?

Comment: Seems like a `position: relative/absolute` problem. But without code I cannot determine the problem.

Comment: code is the same how position can be replaced? I think problem is in windows height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `$ArrowNavigatorOptions: {}` change  `$AutoCenter:` to `0`

```
 $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
       $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$, 
       $AutoCenter: 0                               
 }
```

Then you can control arrows with css `style="top: 20px"` in elements

```
<span u="arrowleft" class="jssora" style="top: 20px; left: 8px;"></span>
<span u="arrowright" class="jssora" style="top: 20px; right: 8px;"></span>
```